# unable to insert to Child in Div with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript and struck at the point where I am getting errors while inserting two elements, one is-page element and second is Button in the span tag, into one div elements.

```js
document.getElementById('buttonForAddingItemToTheList').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var getElementFromTheInput = document.getElementById('inputItemOfHtml').value;

  //list item for page
  var toCreateTheElementOfList = document.createElement('p');

  //button tag
  var toCreateTheButton = document.createElement('button');
  toCreateTheButton.innerText = "Remove";

  //span tag
  var toCreateTheSpanForButton = document.createElement('span');
  toCreateTheSpanForButton.setAttribute('class', 'classForTheButtonCreateByJavaScript');

  //div tag
  var toCreateTheElementOfDivContainer = document.createElement('div');
  toCreateTheElementOfDivContainer.setAttribute('class', 'divContainerCreatedInJavaScript');
  toCreateTheElementOfList.innerText = getElementFromTheInput;
  toCreateTheSpanForButton.appendChild(toCreateTheButton);
  toCreateTheElementOfDivContainer.appendChild(toCreateTheElementOfLists);
  toCreateTheElementOfDivContainer.appendChild(toCreateTheSpanForButton);

  document.getElementById('containerToStoreListItem').appendChild(toCreateTheElementOfDivContainer);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter List Item Here..." id="inputItemOfHtml"><br><br>
<button id="buttonForAddingItemToTheList">Add</button><br><br><br>
<div id="containerToStoreListItem">

</div>
```

Comment: We created you a snippet by clicking [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52733580/edit) and then the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: `toCreateTheElementOfLists` should be `toCreateTheElementOfList`

Comment: Try using jQuery instead plain javacsript that will be lot easier.

Comment: @CataJohn thanks for correcting me, but still it is not working

Comment: @Mustkeem, i understand what you are trying to say, but i want to be a master in Vanilla JavaScript

Comment: The error console is your friend it tells you *Uncaught ReferenceError: toCreateTheElementOfLists is not defined"* . **Always** check the error console and try and fix the error.

Comment: @JonP, bro, actually i am really new to programming so i think it will take me time to learn, how to read code.. Thanx for your advice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is typo error in your code

```
toCreateTheElementOfDivContainer.appendChild(toCreateTheElementOfLists);
```

it should be

```
 toCreateTheElementOfDivContainer.appendChild(toCreateTheElementOfList);
```

```js
document.getElementById('buttonForAddingItemToTheList').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var getElementFromTheInput = document.getElementById('inputItemOfHtml').value;

  //list item for page
  var toCreateTheElementOfList = document.createElement('p');

  //button tag
  var toCreateTheButton = document.createElement('button');
  toCreateTheButton.innerText = "Remove";

  //span tag
  var toCreateTheSpanForButton = document.createElement('span');
  toCreateTheSpanForButton.setAttribute('class', 'classForTheButtonCreateByJavaScript');

  //div tag
  var toCreateTheElementOfDivContainer = document.createElement('div');
  toCreateTheElementOfDivContainer.setAttribute('class', 'divContainerCreatedInJavaScript');
  toCreateTheElementOfList.innerText = getElementFromTheInput;
  toCreateTheSpanForButton.appendChild(toCreateTheButton);
  toCreateTheElementOfDivContainer.appendChild(toCreateTheElementOfList);
  toCreateTheElementOfDivContainer.appendChild(toCreateTheSpanForButton);

  document.getElementById('containerToStoreListItem').appendChild(toCreateTheElementOfDivContainer);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter List Item Here..." id="inputItemOfHtml"><br><br>
<button id="buttonForAddingItemToTheList">Add</button><br><br><br>
<div id="containerToStoreListItem">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo mistake in third last line

`toCreateTheElementOfLists` should be `toCreateTheElementOfList`

```
toCreateTheElementOfDivContainer.appendChild(toCreateTheElementOfList);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2wsuj0fr/